# How to create a drop down list with individual information for each selection in xhtml

Tags: html, xhtml

I would like to know how to create a drop-down list with individual information for each selection in XHTML. If I choose the selection "first list" I would get only the questions for fossil fuels.
Here is my code, but it doesn't work and I really don't know how to do it right...

```
<form>
    <select name="first list">
        <option value="fossile fuels"
                input="first list">fossil fuels</option>
        <option value="renewable energy"
                input="second list"> renewable energy</option>
        
    <ul name="first list">
        <li>fossil fuels</li>
    </ul>
    <ol name="first list">
        <li>Do you think fossil fuels are harmful?<input type="radio" name="first list" value="fossil fuels" /></li>
        <li>Do you think we need to use fossil fuels?<input type="radio" name="first list" value="fossil fuels" /></li>
    </ol>
        
    <ul name="second list">
        <li>renewable energy</li>
    </ul>
    <ol name="second list">
        <li>do you think renewable energy is good for the planet?<input type="radio" name="second list" value="renewable energy" /></li>
        <li>Do you think renewable energy is expensive?<input type="radio" name="second list" value="renewable energy" /></li>
    </ol>
    </select>   
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a script and additional classes to your file.

I added a `class="selector"` to your `dropdown` select. I added a `class="selections fossil"` and `class="selections energy"` to the individual selections and wrapped them in `divs`. I added a style d`isplay: none;` for the `energy` class so only the `fossil div` is visible.

Here is the final code:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("selector")[0].addEventListener("change",function(event){

  if (event.target.value == "renewable energy"){
    document.getElementsByClassName("fossil")[0].style.display = "none";
    document.getElementsByClassName("energy")[0].style.display = "block";
    return;
  }

  document.getElementsByClassName("energy")[0].style.display = "none";
  document.getElementsByClassName("fossil")[0].style.display = "block";

})
```

```css
.energy {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <select class="selector" name="first list">
        <option value="fossile fuels"
                input="first list">fossil fuels</option>
        <option value="renewable energy"
                input="second list"> renewable energy</option>
    </select>
        
    <div class="selections fossil">
        <ul name="first list">
            <li>fossil fuels</li>
        </ul>
        <ol name="first list">
            <li>Do you think fossil fuels are harmful?<input type="radio" name="first list" value="fossil fuels" /></li>
            <li>Do you think we need to use fossil fuels?<input type="radio" name="first list" value="fossil fuels" /></li>
        </ol>
    </div>

    <div class="selections energy">
        <ul name="second list">
            <li>renewable energy</li>
        </ul>
        <ol name="second list">
            <li>do you think renewable energy is good for the planet?<input type="radio" name="second list" value="renewable energy" /></li>
            <li>Do you think renewable energy is expensive?<input type="radio" name="second list" value="renewable energy" /></li>
        </ol>
    </div>   
</form>
```

Alternatively, you can copy this code block as well to view it fully:

```html
<style>
    .energy {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<form>
    <select class="selector" name="first list">
        <option value="fossile fuels"
                input="first list">fossil fuels</option>
        <option value="renewable energy"
                input="second list"> renewable energy</option>
    </select>
        
    <div class="selections fossil">
        <ul name="first list">
            <li>fossil fuels</li>
        </ul>
        <ol name="first list">
            <li>Do you think fossil fuels are harmful?<input type="radio" name="first list" value="fossil fuels" /></li>
            <li>Do you think we need to use fossil fuels?<input type="radio" name="first list" value="fossil fuels" /></li>
        </ol>
    </div>

    <div class="selections energy">
        <ul name="second list">
            <li>renewable energy</li>
        </ul>
        <ol name="second list">
            <li>do you think renewable energy is good for the planet?<input type="radio" name="second list" value="renewable energy" /></li>
            <li>Do you think renewable energy is expensive?<input type="radio" name="second list" value="renewable energy" /></li>
        </ol>
    </div>   
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementsByClassName("selector")[0].addEventListener("change",function(event){

        if (event.target.value == "renewable energy"){
            document.getElementsByClassName("fossil")[0].style.display = "none";
            document.getElementsByClassName("energy")[0].style.display = "block";
            return;
        }

        document.getElementsByClassName("energy")[0].style.display = "none";
        document.getElementsByClassName("fossil")[0].style.display = "block";

    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was really helpfull !